# How does one assign values to messages with arrays in C++

Tags: c++, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is probably more C++ focused, but here is my issue:

```
int8_t vi[height * width];
// vi has had work done on it between here
nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid debMap;
debMap.data = vi; // error here
```

The resulting error is:

```
no operator "=" matches these operands -- operand types are: std::vector<int8_t, std::allocator<int8_t>> = int8_t [height * width]
```

Now in python something like this would be an issue. In the past I have been using memcpy to get around this, but I am less certain that that is the approach to take for this.

How can I add array data to a message with an array.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363764/how-does-one-assign-values-to-messages-with-arrays-in-c++/) by [cwillia109](https://answers.ros.org/users/51647/cwillia109/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2020-10-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [praskot](https://answers.ros.org/users/29965/praskot/) on 2020-10-19**:
I believe, one brute force method is,

```
for (int i = 0; i<height*width; i++) {
  debMap.data.pushback(vi[i]);
}
```

I'm dunno if there is a way to directly assign it to data. May be treated debMap.data as `std::vector` and use one of the suggested methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259297/how-do-you-copy-the-contents-of-an-array-to-a-stdvector-in-c-without-looping).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here's one way to do it:

```
debMap.data.assign(vi, vi + height * width);
```

Cribbed from [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2434208/1270789).

---

Originally posted by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) with karma: 541 on 2020-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cwillia109](https://answers.ros.org/users/51647/cwillia109/) on 2020-10-22**:
This worked like a charm. Thank you!